# TSQL - compare tables

Tags: t-sql, compare

I want to create a stored procedure that compares the results of two queries.  If the results of the 2nd table can be found in the first, print 'YES', otherwise, print 'No'.

Table 1:

```
SELECT     dbo.Roles.RoleName, dbo.UserRoles.RoleID
FROM         dbo.Roles LEFT OUTER JOIN
dbo.UserRoles ON dbo.Roles.RoleID = dbo.UserRoles.RoleID
WHERE     (dbo.Roles.PortalID = 0) AND (dbo.UserRoles.UserID = 2)
```

Table 2:

```
Declare @RowData as nvarchar(2000)
Set @RowData = ( SELECT EditPermissions FROM vw_XMP_DMS_Documents where DocumentID = 2)
Select Data
from dbo.split(@RowData, ',')
```

For example.

Table 1:

```
John
Jack
James
```

Table 2:

```
John
Sally
Jane
```

> Print 'YES'

Is this possible?

Comment: Does YES mean "different" or "same"? I ask because the set "John Sally Jane" is *not* contained in the set "John Jack James". So why "YES"?

Comment: Yes means match. it would be yes because John is in both set 1 and 2.

Comment: match what? All rows or per row?

Comment: wow, so fast! All rows. So the values yes or no could be assigned to a variable. Thank you!

Comment: Read my 1st comment please: why does your exampele have "YES"?

Comment: @gbn: Because `the results of the 2nd table can be found in the first`. In other words, `YES` indicates that the inner join of the two result sets (by a Name column, apparently) is not empty.

Comment: Correct Andriy. The yes no stuff is an answer to my query. "is the results of the 2nd table, in the 1st. if so, do something like print true, or I could Select @answer as 'Yes'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using temporary tables because I dont know which format your tables has.

```
SELECT     dbo.Roles.RoleName, dbo.UserRoles.RoleID 
INTO #t1
FROM         dbo.Roles LEFT OUTER JOIN 
dbo.UserRoles ON dbo.Roles.RoleID = dbo.UserRoles.RoleID 
WHERE     (dbo.Roles.PortalID = 0) AND (dbo.UserRoles.UserID = 2) 


Declare @RowData as nvarchar(2000) 
Set @RowData = ( SELECT EditPermissions FROM vw_XMP_DMS_Documents where DocumentID = 2) 
Select Data 
INTO #t2
from dbo.split(@RowData, ',') 


select case when exists (select 1 from #t1 where RoleName = t.Data) then 'yes' else 'no' end answer, Data 
into #tmp
from #t2 t

select * from #tmp
```

I am not 100 % sure this is what you want. So I am guessing.

added this after understanding the question

```
if exists(select 1 from #t2 t2 join #t1 t1 on t1.RoleName = t2.data) 
print 'permsGranted' 
ELSE print 'permsNotGranted'
```

Comment: Hmm... This outputs a yes or no per column.  I actually want to assign "yes" or "no" to a variable instead . It would look a bit like set @answer to either 'yes' or 'no'. Is this possible?

Comment: you can redirect your answer to a table, or a table variable. Tables is TSQLs answer to arrays. 
select 'yes' as answer into #tmp

Comment: /* is this what you mean? it doesnt seem to work */
select 'yes' as answer into case when exists (
      select 1 
      from #t1 
      where RoleName = t.Data) 
       then 'yes' 
       else 'no' 
       end answer, Data 
from #t2 t

Comment: Got it :)  
set @permission = (select COUNT(*) from #tmp where answer = 'yes')

If (@permission > 0)
 print 'permsGranted'
ELSE
 print 'permsNotGranted'